# Convert MS Access Color Code to Hex in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ms-access

Is there a method to convert MS Access Color codes to Hex in C#?

```
e.g.

 - (white) 16777215 -> #FFFFFF
 - (black) 0        -> #000000
 - (blue)  16711680 -> #0000FF
```

Here are some reference tables I found on stackoverflow

- http://www.endprod.com/colors/invcol.htm
- http://cloford.com/resources/colours/500col.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can convert to hex like so:

```
 string hexValue = "#" + 16777215.ToString("X");
```

Or wrap it up in a method:

```
 public static string AccessToHex(int colorCode) {
      return "#" + colorCode.ToString("X");
 }
```

Comment: I didn't realize it was so simple, Thank you! I'm able to verify this @ http://www.statman.info/conversions/hexadecimal.html

Comment: According to @Pierre-Luc Pineault's comment, a swap is required:
You must convert the value to hexadecimal, then flip the first two digits with the last two. For example, converting the raw value of 16711680 for blue gives a hex value of FF0000. However, the value for blue is 0000FF.

Answer (score 7):

You need to convert the value to hexadecimal, then flip the first two digits with the last two. For example, converting the raw value of 16711680 for blue gives an hex value of FF0000. However, the value for blue is 0000FF; a swap is required (So yes, the other answer is wrong...)

The value is also padded to always have the 6 required digits.

```
string rawHex = msAccessColorCode.ToString("X").PadLeft(6, '0');
string hexColorCode = "#" + rawHex.Substring(4, 2) + rawHex.Substring(2, 2) + rawHex.Substring(0, 2);
```

To do the reverse (hex -> Ms Acces), simply do the steps the other way around. Strip the extra `#` character, flip back the first/last two values and convert that number from base 16 to base 10.

```
string input = "#0000FF";
string hexColorCode = input.TrimStart('#');
string rawHex = hexColorCode.Substring(4, 2) + hexColorCode.Substring(2, 2) + hexColorCode.Substring(0, 2);
string result = Convert.ToInt32(rawHex, 16).ToString(); //16711680
```

Please note that `Intew.Max` is set to `0x7FFFFFFF` (And our color codes cap at `0xFFFFFF`), so it's completely safe to use `Convert.ToInt32` here instead of `Int64`.

Comment: How do we do the reverse?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I edited the answer to include it :)